# Данные отправляются в форму только при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

У меня есть форма на главной странице, и форма заказа на другой странице. На главной странице я прописываю два текстовых поля, и они должны при сабмите перенаправиться на другую страницу и встать в другую форму. Но встают они только после перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: Без примера сложно представить

Comment: ясновидцев здесь нет, показывайте код

Comment: извиняюсь, сейчас

Comment: Причем тут ajax если вы со страницы на страницу данные передаёте? Тут не ajax тогда.. Либо не правильно сформировали проблему.